# Excel with AND, IF, MAX

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, max, excel-2010

I can't quit figure out what I am doing wrong here, I know how to do the formula in multiple steps but can not figure out how to do it in one step all together. So what I am trying to do here is in column A there is numbers 1-27 and in column B there is a weight assigned to them.

The problem I have is I have to find the max weigh in the values given. As you can see I have put from 1 to 10 and the max load should be 50. If i do it the easy way I can get that. On the right side you see a long formula and that is me trying to combine all the formulas into one. But the answers keeps coming out to 235 which is the biggest value I have. Can someone please help me figure out what I am doing wrong?
[image: My excel file screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You might want to check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Formatting your question correctly will go a long way to getting you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: I will do that next time!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just hide the intermediates columns?

Comment: The problem is I have to do it with out adding any columns. I do not understand what i am doing wrong

Comment: Quick Tip: No one likes giant paragraphs.  Try editing your question and breaking that up into no more than 2 sentences per paragraph. It'll be much easier to read and you'll get better responses.

Comment: Let me get this right.  Using your 2 original columns, you want to find the max of every 'weight' where column A is <=10? Is that right?

Comment: Yes correct but the max or min can change to any number. So the formula has to reference that number

Comment: I think you're incredibly close.  Remove your `=true`.  Also, instead of just hitting `Enter` when you're done, you need to make it an array formula by using `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`. Any luck?

Comment: When I do Ctrl+Shift+Enter it gives me 0 with or without the True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I learned today that the `And()` function doesn't work inside of an array formula! In any case, try this:

`=MAX(
    IF(A3:A29>=$G$1,
        IF(A3:A29<=$G$2,$B$3:$B$29)
    )
  )`

(and don't forget to `ctrl+shift+enter`)

Comment: THANKS A LOT!! Although I have one question how did you come up with using two IF statements?

Comment: I knew from trial and error that `if()` worked inside the array formula but `and()` did not.  So why not try 2 `if()` in a row?

Comment: If you want a slightly more concrete answer, `and()` returns True/False while `if()` returns the entire array.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an array formula. I tried your data and i found out that the following one works:

```
 =MAX(IF((A3:A29>=$G$1)*(A3:A29<=$G$2);B3:B29;0))
```

The "multiplication" is a workaround to the unavailable "AND" operator in array formulas.

Some "workarounds" to the unavailable logical operators are described in this [link](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/12/04/logical-operations-in-array-formulas/).

Just make sure that after you type this formula, you don't just press "Enter" but "Ctrl+Shift+Enter".